# Use the HTML Agility Pack to extract lang and lat from Javascript

Tags: asp.net, regex, html-agility-pack

I'd like to use the HTML agility pack to extract the Long and Lat from the following html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = new google.maps.Map($("canvas"), {zoom : 14, mapTypeControl : false, draggable: true, scrollwheel : false, mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, center : new google.maps.LatLng(45.4623, -77.5425)});
</script>
```

ie, I need to fill 2 seperate variables, one with the value 45.4623 and the other with -77.5425

Can anyone please help?  My regex skills aren't great either. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the website it's hard to tell how to match. however, this might work.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
//Load your website...
//doc.Load(....
HtmlNode scriptNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script[contains(text(),'google.maps.Map']");
Match match=      Regex.Match(scriptNode.InnerText, "\\.LatLng\\((?<Lat>-?[\\d.]+), (?<Lng>-?[\\d.]+)\\)");
string latitude = match.Groups["Lat"].Value;
string longitude = match.Groups["Lng"].Value;
```

Only works if the script tag you are after is the first one containing the text `google.maps.Map`.

Comment: That's great, thanks.  I can parse the script node innertext to see if it contains "google.maps.map" and that fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack is great for parsing the angle-bracket nodes, but it knows nothing of the JavaScript syntax inside the  node.  You'd be best to run a regex match on "LatLng\(([^\)]+)\)" and extracting Match.Groups[1].Value.

Comment: Ok thanks, if the script tag above is the third tag on the page, how do I get that with the agility pack?  I assume that I then get the inner text and then match the regex?